# How to filter on a column (for example "WIS Completed" to show either an empty cell or WIP

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

How to filter by a persons name on another column (for example "WIS Completed" to show either an empty cell or WIP by Project Lead)

```
 **WIS Number   WIS Completed   Project Lead** 

1            WIP             J. Bloggs

2            WIS-Completed   J. Bloggs

3            (Empty)         J. Bloggs
```

To show only by WIS numbers which have WIP or are (Empty)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new view on your list and you'd set the filters to be WIS Completed is equal to WIP OR WIS Completed is equal to and leave the field blank. This should get you the results you desire.

Assuming those are your only options for WIS Completed, you could simply create the filter as WIS Completed is not equal to WIS-Completed.

If you are trying to show the current user their not complete projects, then it would be Project Lead is equal to [Me] and WIS Completed is not equal to WIS-Completed or WIS Completed is not equal to Stopped.

Comment: I have tried that however it then shows all Project Leads not just the one person I want to see.

Comment: Then you could use the list view filters to further refine from this base view, or set the view to group by user, or add an AND filter where project lead is equal to the users name.

Comment: The coding for filter by Project Lead is not available.

I currently have Show the items when column "Project Lead" contains (the name) AND when column "WIS Completed" is equal to (Blank) OR "WIS Completed" is equal to "WIP"

This is then showing many project leads not their own

Comment: Is it supposed to show the current user their projects? if so I'd do it like this: Project lead is equal to [Me] and WIS Completed is not equal to WIS-Completed (assuming your statuses are blank, WIP and WIS-Completed)

Comment: That hasn't worked either :(

Comment: Apologies, this has worked, however there is another status "Stopped" which I would also not like to see in this view

Comment: Added as another not equal too filter - Your a Genius! Thank you so much :)

Comment: Awesome, updated the answer to include that piece too.